# How to convert an NSString into an int

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I want to compare 2 numbers.

1. The user has to enter a code(here 1) in and Textfield in an ViewController.
2. The entered number will be compared with each other if it matches the app should switch to an other tab that is defined in each code.

and this is what i got so far

```
int a,b,c,zz;
a=1;
b=2;
c=3;

- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if (sender != self.done) 
      return;
    if (self.zahlencode.text.length > 0)
    {
       zz =self.zahlencode.text;
       if(zz == a)
       {
         zweiViewController *source = [segue sourceViewController];
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call `intValue` on your string:

```
NSString * intString = @"122";

int myInt = [intString intValue];
```

If from a textField:

```
int textFieldInt = [yourTextField.text intValue];
```

You can also use this for other types of value, like:

```
CGFloat textFieldFloat = [yourTextField.text floatValue];
double textFieldDouble = [yourTextField.text doubleValue];
// etc ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
int myInt = [someString integerValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int a,b,c,zz;
a=1;
b=2;
c=3;

- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if (sender != self.done) 
      return;
    if (self.zahlencode.text.length > 0)
    {
       zz =[self.zahlencode.text intValue];
       if(zz == a)
       {
         zweiViewController *source = [segue sourceViewController];
       }
    }
}
```